# How do i rebind the javascript to elements in angular2 component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have defined some custom scripts in javascript file for my angular2 application. When i navigate to other component and come back to previous one, the scripts are not being binded to the html elements since the js file is not loaded the second time. How can i rebind the scripts to the html elements of a component in angular2? Or reload the js file needed by the component every time i navigate to that component?

**Updated with Code**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**myjs.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnNext').click(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

**vendor.ts**

```
// Angular
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';
// RxJS
import 'rxjs';
// Other vendors for example jQuery, Lodash or Bootstrap
// You can import js, ts, css, sass, ...
import '../public/css/bootstrap.css';
import '../public/css/style.css';
import '../public/js/bootstrap.js';
import '../public/js/myjs.js';
```

**modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-modal',
    template: `
        <button type="button" id="btnNext" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
        Launch demo modal
        </button>

         <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" (click)="goToNextView()">Go to next view </button>
    `
 })
 export class ModalComponent {
     constructor(
         private router: Router
     ){}

     goToNextView(){
         this.router.navigate(['/next']);
      }

 }
```

**next-view.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-view',
    template: `
        <b>Hello this is my next route.</b>
        <button class="btn-secondary btn-lg" (click)="goToModal()">Go Back</button>
    `
})
export class NextViewComponent {
    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ){}

    goToModal(){
         this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component'
import { NextViewComponent } from './next-view.component';
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path:'',
        redirectTo: '/',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path:'',
        component: ModalComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'next',
        component: NextViewComponent
    }
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';
import { NextViewComponent } from './next-view.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ModalComponent,
        NextViewComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Initially my app looks like this :

[image]

when i click the Launch demo modal:

[image]

when i navigate to 'next' route:

[image]

when i click 'Go Back' and come to the initial page then my modal wont open. I did a lot of research on that and found that the js i have include is not binded to the element of the component when i navigate back to that component.

SO HOW CAN I REBIND MY JS TO THE ELEMENTS? If it is not how we do things in angular2 then please guide me to how to do it correctly.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example so we can reproduce the issue? The reason could be a lot of things and your question will be flagged as unclear the way it is right now.

Comment: are you talking about script tags ? if so, angular 2 is not meant to work like that...

Comment: @n00dl3 I have separate js files for some functionalities, which i have include via

Comment: included via what ?

Comment: @n00dl3 sorry for the incomplete line. I have included via vendor.ts like this 

`import 'js/myjs.js';

Comment: Maybe you could edit and describe what you are doing because " the scripts are not being binded to the html elements since the js file is not loaded the second time" does not make any sense to me. We don't even know what these scripts are doing neither your component...

Comment: @n00dl3 I have updated my question with a working set of code. (you have to config webpack though). Can you please lead a way for me?

Comment: @echonax I have updated the question with minimal code. I think it is a clear question now.

Comment: Why don't you bind the click event with angular2 to the `<button id="btnNext">` inside modal component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that i can include the trigger script in the ngAfterViewInit() to get it working.

Here is how i did it:

**modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-modal',
    template: `
    <button type="button" id="btnNext" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" (click)="goToNextView()">Go to next view </button>
    `
})
export class ModalComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    constructor(
        private router: Router
        ){}

    goToNextView(){
        this.router.navigate(['/next']);
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(){
            $('#btnNext').click(function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
    }
}
```

Remember that typescript will show the error for *$* and *modal*. But it will work. The error will only be shown in console. But if you don't want to see any error in the console also, then just install typings for bootstrap and jquery

`npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

and

`npm install @types/bootstrap --save-dev`

and you will have to import jquery in vendor.ts as:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

and that is it. No error and working scripts.

**It is recommended not to use JQUERY in angular2 application. You can use**

> **ng2-bootstrap** or **ng-bootstrap**

**I only did it due to time constraint of the project.**